# Subsonic Join issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, subsonic

For those of you who are decent with subsonic!

```
        TblNewsCollection col =
            new Select().From(Tables.TblNews)
                .InnerJoin(Tables.TblContent)
                .Paged(currentPage, pageSize)
                .OrderDesc(TblContent.Columns.PubDate)
                .ExecuteAsCollection<TblNewsCollection>();
```

The above works, no problem, but when I try to add a where clause

```
        TblNewsCollection col =
            new Select().From(Tables.TblNews)
                .InnerJoin(Tables.TblContent)
                .Where(TblContent.Columns.UserFK)
                .IsEqualTo(guidUserFK)
                .Paged(currentPage, pageSize)
                .OrderDesc(TblContent.Columns.PubDate)
                .ExecuteAsCollection<TblNewsCollection>();
```

I get this message

```
System.InvalidCastException: Object must implement IConvertible.
at System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter.CoerceValue(Object value, MetaType destinationType) 
System.InvalidCastException: Failed to convert parameter value from a Guid to a String.
```

I've tried it from other fields, for example a bit field in a database it says it can't convert from bool to bit!

Seems to only be an issue on where statements after joins

Answer (score 1):

I found that joins work better using the TableColumnSchema as in the above Northwind example as opposed to the column name.

Answer (score 0):

```
Northwind.CustomerCollection customersByCategory = new Select()
    .From(Northwind.Customer.Schema)
    .InnerJoin(Northwind.Order.Schema)
    .InnerJoin(Northwind.OrderDetail.OrderIDColumn, Northwind.Order.OrderIDColumn)
    .InnerJoin(Northwind.Product.ProductIDColumn, Northwind.OrderDetail.ProductIDColumn)
    .Where("CategoryID").IsEqualTo(5)
    .ExecuteAsCollection<Northwind.CustomerCollection>();
```

There's an example that supposedly works.  If that helps anyone help me!